# Firefox Fullscreen Preferences

Tags: firefox, video, fullscreen

I opened the webpage [vimeo.com](http://vimeo.com) to view a video, using Firefox 28.0 for Windows. I clicked the Fullscreen button to watch that video in fullscreen. Firefox asked me if I wanted to *Allow* or *Deny* vimeo.com to go fullscreen, and offered to remember my choice. I accidentally clicked Deny, and also ticked the checkbox *Remember my choice for this website*.

Now, when I click the fullscreen button on the video, nothing happens, simply because Firefox remembers that I wanted to deny vimeo.com from going fullscreen. I want to undo that action, or in other words, I want Firefox to forget about (clear) this preference.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Type "about:permissions" in the search bar and press [Enter].
2. Click on "www.vimeo.com" and/or "vimeo.com" in the left bar (search
   for "vimeo" in the search bar if there are many websites), and
   select "Always Ask" at "Fulscreen".

If that doesn't work, you can delete Vimeo's cookies at the same page or simply click on "Forget this website", which will delete everything related to that website.

<sub>Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/938781</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/983083). I believe it will help you.

In summary you can type `about:permissions` into your address bar and change the settings there.